# Position at left border of fixed width auto margin

Tags: html, css

I have a centered page:

```
#page-wrap {
     width: 800px;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This creates a centered layout like this:

```
<-- auto --><-----------------    800px    -----------------><-- auto -->
```

Now I would like to attach two small divs with menu items to the left and right of the page:

```
<-- auto --><-----------------    800px    -----------------><-- auto -->
            <div class="is-left"/>     <div class="is-right"/>
```

The divs are supposed to stay on top of the content:

```
#is-left {
    fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
}
```

Before adding the margin auto, it was easy to position the two divs using `left:0` and `right:0`.

How can I position the divs at the left and right border of the fixed width page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `DIV`s have fixed position, you'll need to use CSS [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to position them:

```
div.is-left {
  left: calc(50% - 400px);
}

div.is-right {
  right: calc(50% - 400px);
}
```

[**Example Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/31hoowdk/)

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect!

Answer (score 2):

Using flexbox is the best way nowadays. Check my example here: http://codepen.io/tomekbuszewski/pen/LGdRLa

I am creating two boxes both 50% width of parent element. Flexbox takes care of placing them next to each other.

```
#page-wrap {
    display: flex;
    width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
}

.block {
    height: 200px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

-- edit --

Don't `position: absolute` of `position: fixed` for simple layout positioning, there are other, proper tools for that ;-)

Comment: How do I make the divs stay at the top with this approach when scrolling so that the menu stays visible?

Comment: If you need to keep your `div`s positioned on top, this is the place to use `position: fixed`. But use in on the container - place them in a `header` element or something like that.